# Parsing JSON data from a text column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have `JSON` in a file as follows:

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ cat cgs_test.json
{"technology":"AAA","vendor":"XXX","name":"RBNI","temporal_unit":"hour","regional_unit":"cell","dataset_metadata":"{\"name\": \"RBNI\", \"temporal_unit\": \"hour\", \"technology\": \"LTE\", \"is_dimension\": false, \"timestamp_column_pattern\": \"yyyyMMddHHmmss\", \"data_type\": \"PM\", \"source_name\": \"RBNI\", \"intervals_epoch_seconds\": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], \"identifier_column_names\": [\"CELLID\", \"CELLNAME\", \"radio_frequency_band\", \"ENODEBID\", \"ENODEBNAME\", \"SBNID\", \"SITEID\", \"SITENAME\", \"CLUSTER_PRIORITY\", \"CP_SITE\", \"IBC\", \"NETWORK_TIER\", \"SITE_TYPE\", \"T3_FLAG\", \"CLUSTERID\", \"CLUSTERNAME\", \"REGION\", \"NETWORK\"], \"vendor\": \"ZTE\", \"timestamp_column_name\": \"COLLECTTIME\", \"regional_unit\": \"cell\"}","rk":1}
{"technology":"AAA","vendor":"XXX","name":"RRCADD","temporal_unit":"hour","regional_unit":"cell","dataset_metadata":"{\"name\": \"RRCADD\", \"temporal_unit\": \"hour\", \"technology\": \"AAA\", \"is_dimension\": false, \"timestamp_column_pattern\": \"yyyyMMddHHmmss\", \"data_type\": \"PM\", \"source_name\": \"RRCADD\", \"intervals_epoch_seconds\": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], \"identifier_column_names\": [\"CELLID\", \"CELLNAME\", \"radio_frequency_band\", \"ENODEBID\", \"ENODEBNAME\", \"SBNID\", \"SITEID\", \"SITENAME\", \"CLUSTER_PRIORITY\", \"CP_SITE\", \"IBC\", \"NETWORK_TIER\", \"SITE_TYPE\", \"T3_FLAG\", \"CLUSTERID\", \"CLUSTERNAME\", \"REGION\", \"NETWORK\"], \"vendor\": \"XXX\", \"timestamp_column_name\": \"COLLECTTIME\", \"regional_unit\": \"cell\"}","rk":1}
```

and I have loaded this to one temp table:

```
create table temp_json (values text);
\copy temp_json from '/home/xyz/cgs_test.json';
```

Now I want to extract this data into separate columns as:

```
technology 
vendor
name
temporal_unit
regional_unit
dataset_metadata
rk
```

`dataset_metadata` is a JSON column and other columns are strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this question what I did was the following (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3f3fd26120341b076b2074c48150d920)):

This was quite a learning experience for me (+1 for that BTW) so I'll go through the steps in my logic and hopefully this will help you - but I'm doing it for myself really :-)

Step 1:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_1 
(
  json_input TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Step 2:

Populate it with your two records. However, your two records aren't proper JSON - they need a `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end in order for them to be proper JSON - so, I've put them into the `INSERT` at the very beginning of the process - I leave it up to the reader to experiment with what happens if you leave them out - you can put them in later in the process - see below.

There may be a way of not having to do this with a different `JSON` function - beyond my pay grade I'm afraid - but I'd appreciate any suggestions for improvements.

```
INSERT INTO temp_1 VALUES  -- strings copied from the question
('{"technology":"AAA","vendor":"XXX","name":"RBNI","temporal_unit":"hour","regional_unit":"cell","dataset_metadata":"{\"name\": \"RBNI\", \"temporal_unit\": \"hour\", \"technology\": \"LTE\", \"is_dimension\": false, \"timestamp_column_pattern\": \"yyyyMMddHHmmss\", \"data_type\": \"PM\", \"source_name\": \"RBNI\", \"intervals_epoch_seconds\": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], \"identifier_column_names\": [\"CELLID\", \"CELLNAME\", \"radio_frequency_band\", \"ENODEBID\", \"ENODEBNAME\", \"SBNID\", \"SITEID\", \"SITENAME\", \"CLUSTER_PRIORITY\", \"CP_SITE\", \"IBC\", \"NETWORK_TIER\", \"SITE_TYPE\", \"T3_FLAG\", \"CLUSTERID\", \"CLUSTERNAME\", \"REGION\", \"NETWORK\"], \"vendor\": \"ZTE\", \"timestamp_column_name\": \"COLLECTTIME\", \"regional_unit\": \"cell\"}","rk":1}'),
('{"technology":"AAA","vendor":"XXX","name":"RRCADD","temporal_unit":"hour","regional_unit":"cell","dataset_metadata":"{\"name\": \"RRCADD\", \"temporal_unit\": \"hour\", \"technology\": \"AAA\", \"is_dimension\": false, \"timestamp_column_pattern\": \"yyyyMMddHHmmss\", \"data_type\": \"PM\", \"source_name\": \"RRCADD\", \"intervals_epoch_seconds\": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], \"identifier_column_names\": [\"CELLID\", \"CELLNAME\", \"radio_frequency_band\", \"ENODEBID\", \"ENODEBNAME\", \"SBNID\", \"SITEID\", \"SITENAME\", \"CLUSTER_PRIORITY\", \"CP_SITE\", \"IBC\", \"NETWORK_TIER\", \"SITE_TYPE\", \"T3_FLAG\", \"CLUSTERID\", \"CLUSTERNAME\", \"REGION\", \"NETWORK\"], \"vendor\": \"XXX\", \"timestamp_column_name\": \"COLLECTTIME\", \"regional_unit\": \"cell\"}","rk":1}');
```

Then, turn the strings into JSON as follows - this can be done in bulk:

```
--
--  This is to turn the "ordinary" strings into JSON per record. If this isn't
--  done, the process will fail further down. Will work for an arbitrary number
--  of records
--

UPDATE temp_1
SET json_input = '[' || json_input || ']';
```

Step 3:

Create another table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_2
(
  final_json JSON NOT NULL
);
```

Step 4:

Populate this by:

```
INSERT INTO temp_2 SELECT json_input::JSON FROM temp_1;
```

The `::JSON` cast is necessary, otherwise the `INSERT` will fail as `json_input` is of type `TEXT`.

Then, clear down `temp_1':

```
--
--  Clear down temp_1.
--  This is needed for next batch, otherwise you'll have strings beginning 
--  with '[[' and then '[[[' (endings same with multiple ']'s) and so on!
--

DELETE FROM temp_1;
```

Step 5:

Create a table to hold the data:

```
CREATE TABLE json_table
(
  technology TEXT,
  vendor TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  temporal_unit TEXT,
  regional_unit TEXT,
  dataset_metadata JSON,
  rk SMALLINT
);
```

Step 6:

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26742370/470530), I obtained this method to populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO json_table 
SELECT (json_populate_recordset(null::json_table, final_json)).* FROM temp_2;
```

There's another way shown in the fiddle - from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822085/using-json-populate-recordset-without-creating-a-table) - YMMV?

Step 7 - final check:

```
SELECT * FROM json_table;
```

Result:

```
technology  vendor  name    temporal_unit   regional_unit   dataset_metadata    rk
AAA XXX RBNI    hour    cell    "{\"name\": \"RBNI\", \"temporal_unit\": \"hour\", \"technology\": \"LTE\", \"is_dimension\": false, \"timestamp_column_pattern\": \"yyyyMMddHHmmss\", \"data_type\": \"PM\", \"source_name\": \"RBNI\", \"intervals_epoch_seconds\": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], \"identifier_column_names\": [\"CELLID\", \"CELLNAME\", \"radio_frequency_band\", \"ENODEBID\", \"ENODEBNAME\", \"SBNID\", \"SITEID\", \"SITENAME\", \"CLUSTER_PRIORITY\", \"CP_SITE\", \"IBC\", \"NETWORK_TIER\", \"SITE_TYPE\", \"T3_FLAG\", \"CLUSTERID\", \"CLUSTERNAME\", \"REGION\", \"NETWORK\"], \"vendor\": \"ZTE\", \"timestamp_column_name\": \"COLLECTTIME\", \"regional_unit\": \"cell\"}"   1
AAA XXX RRCADD  hour    cell    "{\"name\": \"RRCADD\", \"temporal_unit\": \"hour\", \"technology\": \"AAA\", \"is_dimension\": false, \"timestamp_column_pattern\": \"yyyyMMddHHmmss\", \"data_type\": \"PM\", \"source_name\": \"RRCADD\", \"intervals_epoch_seconds\": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], \"identifier_column_names\": [\"CELLID\", \"CELLNAME\", \"radio_frequency_band\", \"ENODEBID\", \"ENODEBNAME\", \"SBNID\", \"SITEID\", \"SITENAME\", \"CLUSTER_PRIORITY\", \"CP_SITE\", \"IBC\", \"NETWORK_TIER\", \"SITE_TYPE\", \"T3_FLAG\", \"CLUSTERID\", \"CLUSTERNAME\", \"REGION\", \"NETWORK\"], \"vendor\": \"XXX\", \"timestamp_column_name\": \"COLLECTTIME\", \"regional_unit\": \"cell\"}"   1
```

A couple of thoughts:

- Your `dataset_metadata` field doesn't appear to be "proper" JSON - maybe a suitable `REGEXP_REPLACE` and/or a `CAST` might be in order? I don't know the process by which you get your `/home/xyz/cgs_test.json` file - but it **may** be worth looking at how the record is generated - ideally, you should correct any issues as early in the pipeline as possible.
- I don't know your exact circumstances, but you should carefully consider the advice [here](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/) - you **might** want to hive your metadata off into a separate table with a `FOREIGN KEY` connecting it to the parent record?

Comment: Thanks.. what's that || along with '['. also could you please suggest some way to add it via some command. can we remove manually process to add '['.. sometimes files will be huge

Comment: Ooops - the link to the fiddle wasn't there - it is now! I'll modify it so that the process is simpler!

Comment: You can do `UPDATE temp_1 SET json_input = '[' || json_input || ']';` and further down, you `DELETE FROM temp_1` - see the revised fiddle and the explanation - this can be done in bulk! HTH!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I added '[' and ']' and when I use copy command to load temp_1 table.. \copy temp_1 from '/home/xyz/cgs_test.json'; table get loaded and has removed all '\' on its own.  I cannot query like this SELECT json_input::JSON FROM temp_1;

Comment: but I can query if I use insert statement like yours

Comment: @vikrantrana - I've put up a solution for bulk `UPDATE`ing of the input strings. Let me know if this is satisfactory!

Comment: you answer is great and accepted but if I use copy command like \copy temp_1 from '/home/eksinvi/cgs_test.json'; and then run update statement and if I do run select like below.. I am getting this.. SELECT json_input::JSON FROM temp_1;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "name" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ..."regional_unit":"cell","dataset_metadata":"{"name...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118167/discussion-between-vikrant-rana-and-verace).

Answer (score 4):

COPY is not intended to populate each line to column as-is. It will break some line formatting in nested json encode.

Instead of COPY you may use [`pg_read_file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) admin function to read the file  and then split this text per-line:

```
create temp table temp_json as
select v::json 
 from regexp_split_to_table(
     trim(pg_read_file('/tmp/json'), E'\n'), 
 '[\n\r]+') as v;
```

So we see that given JSON is correct. Let's reformat as needed:

```
select v->>'technology', 
v->>'vendor', 
v->>'name', 
v->>'temporal_unit', 
v->>'regional_unit', 
v->>'dataset_metadata', 
v->>'rk' 
from temp_json ;

-[ RECORD 1 ]--
?column? | AAA
?column? | XXX
?column? | RBNI
?column? | hour
?column? | cell
?column? | {"name": "RBNI", "temporal_unit": "hour", "technology": "LTE", "is_dimension": false, "timestamp_column_pattern": "yyyyMMddHHmmss", "data_type": "PM", "source_name": "RBNI", "intervals_epoch_seconds": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], "identifier_column_names": ["CELLID", "CELLNAME", "radio_frequency_band", "ENODEBID", "ENODEBNAME", "SBNID", "SITEID", "SITENAME", "CLUSTER_PRIORITY", "CP_SITE", "IBC", "NETWORK_TIER", "SITE_TYPE", "T3_FLAG", "CLUSTERID", "CLUSTERNAME", "REGION", "NETWORK"], "vendor": "ZTE", "timestamp_column_name": "COLLECTTIME", "regional_unit": "cell"}
?column? | 1
-[ RECORD 2 ]-
?column? | AAA
?column? | XXX
?column? | RRCADD
?column? | hour
?column? | cell
?column? | {"name": "RRCADD", "temporal_unit": "hour", "technology": "AAA", "is_dimension": false, "timestamp_column_pattern": "yyyyMMddHHmmss", "data_type": "PM", "source_name": "RRCADD", "intervals_epoch_seconds": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], "identifier_column_names": ["CELLID", "CELLNAME", "radio_frequency_band", "ENODEBID", "ENODEBNAME", "SBNID", "SITEID", "SITENAME", "CLUSTER_PRIORITY", "CP_SITE", "IBC", "NETWORK_TIER", "SITE_TYPE", "T3_FLAG", "CLUSTERID", "CLUSTERNAME", "REGION", "NETWORK"], "vendor": "XXX", "timestamp_column_name": "COLLECTTIME", "regional_unit": "cell"}
?column? | 1
```

You could also cast nested JSON in dataset_metadata to JSON datatype and process it further as you wish. For example,

```
select v->>'name', 
  cast((v->>'dataset_metadata') as json)->'vendor' as meta_vendor
  from temp_json ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------
?column?    | RBNI
meta_vendor | "ZTE"
-[ RECORD 2 ]-------
?column?    | RRCADD
meta_vendor | "XXX"
```

Comment: Excellent answer which is much better than mine - you're correcting the problems with the input at the very first hurdle - the loading into a table part (+1)! How would you hive off the `dataset_metadata` part as a child table using an `FK`? It looks tricky because of the array `identifier_column_names`?

Comment: @Vérace, I didn't see any problems with `identifier_column_names`. Leave as json array, or convert to some `enum` array (if possible values are known) or `text[]` with `select (select array_agg(s) from  json_array_elements_text(cast((v->>'dataset_metadata') as json)->'identifier_column_names') as s) from temp_json ;`

Comment: I am getting user must be superuser but I like answer.. both answers seems to be good